# Get motherboard or hard serial from code

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to get motherboard or hard serial from code ?

i want to get it for my program that other people can't use it on their computers.can anybody give me another way if this way isn't good?

Comment: No way is sure to work.  With virtualization, the user can choose any serial number as they wish.

Comment: The only sure way is: don't give them your program.  Then they can't run it.

Answer (score 1):

The project was created to resolve similar problem iOS:
https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5
And I think you can use the idea to create some lib which will provide some unique id for you hardware

One more article describes a solution of the problem:

http://wranglingmacs.blogspot.com/2009/04/getting-byhost-string.html?m=1

Comment: please delete your answer that i delete this question